# Redirect 404's within a certain directory to index.php

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all 404 messages to the index page, but only within certain directories/categories.

For example

404's within the following dir's will display as normal

www.foo.com/

www.foo.com/blah

404's in the following dir's will redirect to index.php

www.foo.com/bar

www.foo.com/fizz/buzz

So far I've found that the following will redirect all 404's to the index page with an OK status.

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html
```

Is it possible to do this directory specifc?

Answer (score 1):

As in the first comment, `error_page` can be defined in location level.

```
location ^~ /baz {
    error_page /index.html;
}
```

Old answer or another way to achieve this: 
You need to use **try_files** for [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). 
Name is obvious. Nginx tries to open for given path if exists. 
if can't find, it tries the next. So your rule should look like this.

Comment: Also error_page sets all the 404s in all paths of server definition. So you can't use it.

Comment: that isn't true. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page error_page can be defined on the location level and only inherited if not defined at the current level

Comment: I read that if using try_files, if any element on the page can't be loaded (such as an image or script) it'll automatically redirect - is this true?

Comment: Also, will this be recursive? I.e anything under /baz/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx

Comment: @Drifter104 Thank you for correcting me. you are right. it's possible to use for different locations. I am going to update my answer.

Comment: @jblz Yes it covers all directories since we are using "^~". But as Drifter104's mention i have to correct the answer. and of course this rule applies to images or any other resources that is not available.